# Is there any way for SSH to automatically insert password?

Tags: ssh, passwords

I am currently developing some work in clients and servers application and my college allows us to use their machines (linux) to host and test the apps.

My problem is that every single time I want to ssh into the machine the server prompts me to insert the password. I managed to use the information [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#platform-windows) to use a key in order to login but it still asks me for my password into the machine.

Using Putty I can save my password and login straight, is there anyway to do this using this command:

```
ssh -t (myUser@theSSHLink) -p 22
```

via Git Bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
USERHOST="myUser@theSSHLink"

cd ${HOME}

if [ ! -f ".ssh/id_rsa" ]; then
    ssh-keygen -t rsa
fi

ssh $USERHOST mkdir -p .ssh
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh $USERHOST 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Running the above will ask for your password (from the user@host) twice. Afterwards, it shouldn't ask for a password when you try to ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that did not work :( I entered the password I use to log in into that machine and each time I ssh into it, still get prompted to input password.

Comment: @RafaelMoreira Hm, that should've done the trick. The other option is piping the password from a file (not secure as your password is in plain text). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223491/piping-a-password-located-in-a-file-to-the-ssh-command